# Options for getting paid for hunting or fishing on vacation

Tags: where-on-earth, hunting

Is there any place, no matter where you have to travel to, where we get paid to hunt?

At least, it would be nice to cover partially the costs or even break even.

Comment: You might be able to pick up a bounty for a few pest type animals like Coyotes.

Comment: Wild boars were an issue an Kaua'i when I visited about 4–5 years ago. Dunno if they have bounties on 'em though. I imagine that you'll face tough competition from locals in any well-known hunting ground.

Answer (score 5):

This was covered in [a Houston Chronicle article](http://work.chron.com/paid-hunt-22105.html). You have a few options, generally speaking:

- Guide Services - with some training, you can be a guide for game hunters, and charge good money to take clients on a hunt
- Government hunts/bounties (you can still get $50 for every boar you present in Alberta, Canada)
- hides - anything you hunt, you could learn taxidermy and skin it, and sell the pelt/fur/skin later on for money
- videos/blogging - far more rare than travel blogging, hunting blogs might be the thing. If you can write excitingly about a hunt, with good photos and/or video, it might be monetizable.

Of course each of the above is going to vary in usefulness depending on how much time/inclination you have, but they are options.